# In which case is $|x| = x^2$?

Tags: absolute-value, law-of-large-numbers

i had a exercise in which i had to conclude the law of large numbers.
I couldnt solve it, because they used the following equivalence:

$|x| = x^2$

To be morce specific:
Let be $X_{n} \sim bin(n,p)$ with $X_{n} \sim Z_{1}+..+Z_{n}$. and let be $Z_{1},Z_{2}...$ a continued p-coin flip and $\epsilon > 0$
$P(|\frac{Z_{1}+..+Z_{n}}{n}-p| \geq \epsilon)=P((\frac{X_{n}}{n}-p)^2 \geq \epsilon)\leq\frac{1}{\epsilon}\frac{pq}{n} => lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{\epsilon}\frac{pq}{n} = 0$

My question now, in which case is $|x| = x^2$ correct and why?

Comment: There are exactly three complex numbers $z$ such that $z^2=\lvert z\rvert$. They are $-1,0,1$.

Comment: The question should not be when $|x| = x^2$, but why $P(|\frac{Z_{1}+\ldots+Z_{n}}{n}-p| \geq \epsilon)=P((\frac{X_{n}}{n}-p)^2 \geq \epsilon)$ right? You are the one that assumed that this is because $|x| = x^2$?

Comment: now i see, x has to be 1, -1 or 0. @Winther thats true, now i would like to know why they say $\frac{X_{n}}{n}-p$ is around $0$ or $1$ and no, my tutor said "its because for small numbers you can write $|x| $ as $ x^2$

Comment: They are not saying that. After all, $P(f(Y)\ge \epsilon)=P(g(Y)\ge \epsilon)$ does not necessarily imply $f(Y)=g(Y)$.

Comment: Now i understand! i looked at the fact $f(Y) \neq g(Y)$ but thats truly not the same as $P(f(Y) \geq \epsilon) \neq P(g(Y) \geq \epsilon)$

Comment: It is very hard to understand what you are asking. or how you arrived at the equality above (what are the $Z_k$?), and the last implication is not an implication.

Comment: @copper.hat i will edit it.

Comment: It is not clear to me what your tutor states that you can write $|x|$ as $x^2$ for small $x$. Sounds like rubbish to me.

Comment: @copper.hat thats what i thought. Thats why i am asking on stack.

Comment: I don't follow the $P()=P()$ equality at all. Are you trying to show that the first $P()$  converges in probability to zero ?

Comment: Yes, we had to conclude from $P((\frac{X_{n}}{n}-p)^2 \geq \epsilon)\leq\frac{1}{\epsilon}\frac{pq}{n}$ the law of large numbers by bernoulli, with the additional information that $lim_{n\to\infty} P(|\frac{Z_{1}+..+Z_{n}}{n}-p| \geq \epsilon) = 0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not an answer, but the formulae in the question are bothersome to me.

Chebyshev's inequality states that for a random variable $X$ with
finite expectation $\mu $, finite variance $\operatorname{var} X$ and
$\epsilon>0$ that
$P[|X-\mu| \ge \epsilon] \le { \operatorname{var} X \over \epsilon^2} $.

If $Z_k$ are independent coin flips with probability $p$ of getting a head then $\mu= E Z_k = p$ and $\operatorname{var} Z_k = p(1-p)$.

Then $E [{1 \over n}(Z_1+\cdots+Z_n)] = \mu = p$ and
$\operatorname{var} {1 \over n}(Z_1+\cdots+Z_n) = {1 \over n}\operatorname{var} Z_k = {p (1-p) \over n} $.

Now substitute into Chebyshev's inequality to get
$P[|{1 \over n}(Z_1+\cdots+Z_n) - p| \ge \epsilon] \le {{p (1-p) \over n} \over \epsilon^2}$ and we see that
$\lim_{n \to \infty} P[|{1 \over n}(Z_1+\cdots+Z_n) - p| \ge \epsilon] = 0$

Answer (score 1):

Assuming $x\in \mathbb R$, only $x=0$, $x=-1$ and $x=1$. This happens because

- if $x\ge0$, $|x|=x$, and so the equation becomes $x=x^2$, or $0=x(x-1)$;
- if $x<0$, $|x|=-x$, and the equation is now $-x=x^2$, or $0=x(x+1)$.

Since those are all possible cases, the set of solutions is $\{-1,0,1\}$.

Anyway, that's not the case for $\frac{X_n}n-p$. For instance, let $n=2$ and $p=0.4$, so that $X_n\sim Binom(2;0.4)$. Then $\frac {X_n}n$ is one of the elements of $\{0,\tfrac12, 1\}$. Then $\left|\frac{X_n}n-p\right| \in \{0.4, 0.1, 0.6\}$ and $\left(\frac{X_n}n-p\right)^2 \in \{0.16, 0.01, 0.36\}$. So if $\epsilon=0.2$, then
$$\left|\frac{X_n}n-p\right| \ge \epsilon \quad \iff \quad X_n \in \{0,1\}$$
and
$$\left(\frac{X_n}n-p\right)^2 \ge \epsilon \quad \iff \quad X_n \in \{1\},$$
and hence $$P\left(\left|\frac{X_n}n-p\right| \ge \epsilon\right)>P\left(\left(\frac{X_n}n-p\right)^2 \ge \epsilon \right).$$

So the claim is not true. I imagine there is somewhere some additional assumption for $\epsilon$, such as that this is "small enough" (although that only makes sense for fixed $n$). It is also true that for fixed $\epsilon$, both probabilities become $0$ for $n$ "large enough". Maybe you should check again to see if you overlooked some important remark in the text.

Comment: You don't have to use cases. $|x|=\sqrt{x^2}$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$. Solve for $x$ in $x^2=\sqrt{x^2}$.

Comment: @isthisreallife Better than that, $\lvert x\rvert^2=x^2$. However, cases are fine nontheless.

Comment: I like those. It's just that I find the "two cases" reasoning more natural (or at least rawer, in the sense that I'm just using the definition) for someone who —as this might be the case— is not very familiar with absolute value and its properties.

Comment: @AlejandroNasifSalum I thank you for the correct solution. The information i gave where all information i got form my tutor, sad they are not completely correct.

Answer (score 0):

For non-negative number $x$,  $$ |x| = x^2$$   is the same as $$x = x^2$$ so $x=0$ or $x=1.$

For negative $x$, it is the same as $$-x=x^2$$ with $x=-1$ a solution in negative numbers.

Therefore the only possible solutions are $x=0$, or $x=1$ or $x=-1$.

Comment: What about $x=-1$?

Comment: I fixed it. Thanks for your comment.